# How to access source view that perform segue from within that segue or destination view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a custom `ContainerSegue` inherited from `UIStoryboardSegue`. Within `perform()` method I need to access the `UIView` that performed current segue. How can I do this? Is it possible?

> In other words I need to access the **sender** within `perform()` method.

Comment: if this is some modal presentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller

Comment: No, it is not this:(

Comment: so we need to know more, you can always set controller in prepareForSegue method

Answer (score 3):

A `segue` class doesn't typically keep track of the `sender`, but since you have defined a custom `segue` class called `ContainerSegue`, you can add a `sender` property to it:

```
class ContainerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    // Add this property to hold the sender
    var sender: AnyObject?

    override func perform() {
        if let button = sender as? UIButton, title = button.currentTitle {
            print("button title is \(title)")
        }

        // Add remainder of perform code here
    }
}
```

and then set that in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let containerSegue = segue as? ContainerSegue {
        containerSegue.sender = sender
    }
}
```

---

In a similar manner, if you want to access the `sender` in the `destinationViewController`, add a `sender` property to the `destinationViewController` and set that in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? MyDestinationVC {
        dvc.sender = sender
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
let view = button.superview
```